# Branch To Label But Keep Old Register Values in ARM

Tags: assembly, arm

I am new to ARM and I want to branch to a label i have created but still be able to use the values of the registers I set in the previous part of the program.

My code is

```
    B main

menmow  DEFB    "men went to mow\n",0
manmow  DEFB    "man went to mow\n",0
meadow  DEFB    "Went to mow a meadow\n",0
dog DEFB    "man and his dog, Spot\n",0
men DEFB    "men",0
man DEFB    "man",0

    ALIGN

main    MOV R1, #4
    MOV R2, #0
    MOV R2, #1
    CMP R1,R2
    BNE Verse1
    ;SWI    2
Verse1  
    ADR R0, R1  
    SWI 4
    CMP R1,R2
    BEQ Man
    ADR R0, menmow
    SWI 3
    ;B  Verse2      
Man ADR R0, manmow
    SWI 3
    SWI 2           ; stop
    B main      


;SWI 4 to print integers
```

Comment: But... you can do exactly that with any branch instruction (well, with the possible exception of `bl{x}` overwriting r14). Which part of this code isn't working as expected? What specific undesired behaviour are you observing?

Comment: When i compile my code i get the error of "Label not found on line 18 of file "directory of the file" Verse1 ADR R0,R1.

Comment: i'm thinking thats because its not getting the value from the main label but i'm not sure

Comment: But you _don't_ have a label named "R1"...

Comment: I know thats the problem, i changed the code so it shows the entire program but i am baffled by this error

Comment: `ADR R0,label` is not an instruction.  It is a form of `add r0,pc,#constant` where constant is a distance to the label.  If you want a jump table, then you can use `ldr pc,[r0,r1]` or something like that.  Your table/array would have *menmow* and *manmow* addresses in it.  It looks like you don't want a jump table, but just an array of strings.  There are [numerous questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[arm]+array) in the ARM tag on these topics.  Read on [ADR in the GAS manual.](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/ARM-Opcodes.html#ARM-Opcodes)

Comment: BTW, which compiler do you use? The few that I have used, requite ":" after the label definition. And why doesn't 'b label' do? And is there a secret idea behind this:     MOV R2, #0
    MOV R2, #1

Comment: I finally found out what my problem was, The issue was that when i wanted to print i used ADR R0, my register which copied the address of the register not the actual contents so when i changed ADR to MOV the problem compiled. Also for the compiler i am using the komodo (kmd) environment. Thank you for the help.